# How conversions that creates prvalue are create temporary objects?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, prvalue

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)

> Temporary objects are created .. in the
> following situations:
>
> - conversion that creates a prvalue **(including T(a,b,c) and T{})**

When this can happen? (examples will be appreciated)

What does they mean by **"including T(a,b,c) and T{}"**?

Do `static_cast<T>(e)`, `const_cast<T>(e)`, `dynamic_cast<T>(e)` and `reinterpret_cast<T>(e)` conversions are always evaluate to prvalue?

Comment: the notion of what a converting constructor is has changed in C++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

Comment: Both "conversion" and "including" on that page are links leading to other pages. For a full picture, along with more examples, visit the first 6 pages linked under "conversion" and locate each conversion type that returns a pre-C++17 prvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> When this can happen? (examples will be appreciated)
>
> What does they mean by "including T(a,b,c) and T{}"?

"including T(a,b,c) and T{}" means that T(a,b,c) and T{} are examples of cases where temporary objects are created (until C++17).

> Do `static_cast<T>(e)`, `const_cast<T>(e)`, `dynamic_cast<T>(e)` and `reinterpret_cast<T>(e)` conversions are always evaluate to prvalue?

No. The quoted sentence implies that there are prvalue conversions and non-prvalue conversions, and the latter don't necessarily create temporary objects. If `T` is a reference type, then the conversion is a glvalue.

Comment: @cpper I disagree.

Comment: It would be better to explain what you are saying with simple examples

Comment: @cpper: A "simple example" of what?